# Get attribute of ActiveRecord by name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, attributes

I have a partial, that will be used in many places of a project.

It renders items, related to specified tag, like:

```
@tag.articles.each do |a|
    # render articles
end
```

I need this partial to render not only articles, but any other items, associated with tags.

So, this partial has one parameter **association_name** and looks like this:

```
@tag[association_name].each do |a|
    # render articles
end
```

I call this partial in following ways:

```
# to render articles
render :partial => "items", :locals => {:association_name => "articles"}

# to render videos
render :partial => "items", :locals => {:association_name => "videos"}

# etc.
```

The problem is - i cannot refer fields of Article model in a way:

```
@article[association_name]
```

How to do it and why it does't works ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@article.send(association_name)
```